Inaccessible Object Exception when trying to persist data to database
I am building an insurance management program with hibernate and javaFX. I was trying to persist an object to my database when I encountered the following error.
Apr 26, 2024 11:33:44 AM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
Apr 26, 2024 11:33:44 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.0.2.Final
Apr 26, 2024 11:33:45 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using built-in connection pool (not intended for production use)
Apr 26, 2024 11:33:45 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: Loaded JDBC driver class: org.postgresql.Driver
Apr 26, 2024 11:33:45 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001012: Connecting with JDBC URL [jdbc:postgresql://aws-0-ap-southeast-1.pooler.supabase.com/postgres]
Apr 26, 2024 11:33:45 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=postgres.lfmakwarfqeintgjcseo}
Apr 26, 2024 11:33:45 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Apr 26, 2024 11:33:45 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH10001115: Connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Apr 26, 2024 11:33:45 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl logSelectedDialect
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
Apr 26, 2024 11:33:46 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PoolState stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:postgresql://aws-0-ap-southeast-1.pooler.supabase.com/postgres]
Exception in thread "main" jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1509)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1430)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:55)
    at jakarta.persistence@3.0.0/jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)
    at jakarta.persistence@3.0.0/jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at org.example.insurancemanagementapplication/Entity.Testing.main(Testing.java:16)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.processBootEntities(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.RuntimeMetamodelsImpl.finishInitialization(RuntimeMetamodelsImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:308)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1425)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private java.lang.String Entity.User.id accessible: module org.example.insurancemanagementapplication does not "opens Entity" to unnamed module @7920ba90
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:388)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:364)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:312)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:183)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.ensureAccessibility(ReflectHelper.java:412)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.findField(ReflectHelper.java:402)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessFieldImpl.<init>(PropertyAccessFieldImpl.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessStrategyFieldImpl.buildPropertyAccess(PropertyAccessStrategyFieldImpl.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.EntityRepresentationStrategyPojoStandard.makePropertyAccess(EntityRepresentationStrategyPojoStandard.java:381)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.EntityRepresentationStrategyPojoStandard.<init>(EntityRepresentationStrategyPojoStandard.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.ManagedTypeRepresentationResolverStandard.resolveStrategy(ManagedTypeRepresentationResolverStandard.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:725)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:152)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:92)
    ... 11 more

The following is my code:
@MappedSuperclass
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User that = (User) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id) && Objects.equals(fullName, that.fullName) && Objects.equals(address, that.address) && Objects.equals(phoneNumber, that.phoneNumber) && Objects.equals(email, that.email) && Objects.equals(password, that.password);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, fullName, address, phoneNumber, email, password);
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "system_admin", schema = "public", catalog = "postgres")
public class SystemAdmin extends User {

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        try{
            transaction.begin();
            SystemAdmin systemAdmin = new SystemAdmin();
            systemAdmin.setId("SA1232678");
            systemAdmin.setFullName("Tran Ba Duong");
            systemAdmin.setPassword("Duongsssber123");
            systemAdmin.setEmail("trunDuong0806@gmail.com");
            systemAdmin.setPhoneNumber("0909154614");
            systemAdmin.setAddress("999 Elizabeth street Carlton 3053 VIC");
            entityManager.persist(systemAdmin);

            transaction.commit();
        } finally {
            if (transaction.isActive()){
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            entityManager.close();
            entityManagerFactory.close();
        }

    }

I have been searching the Internet for a potential solution and have found none so far. One thing to note is that I have built a separate non-javafx project and it works just fine. The following images show the 2 project structure. The codes above work just fine with the non-javafx project:
JavaFX project
Non JavaFx project
However, as long as it incorporates it into the java-fx project structure, this problem surfaces. What is the cause of the problem? How can I solve it? Thank you very much

Try adding opens Entity; to your module-info.java file or making your project non-modular by deleting said file.

@Slaw Thank you for your response. I have tried adding opens Entity into the module-info.java. Doing so introduced a complete different exception: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superinterface check failed. Removing the module-info.java file would prevent me from using Java FX. I have tried building a hibernate-only project using the codes above and it could add to the database just fine. This problem only appears when I built the project with Java FX.

JavaFX does not require your own code to be modular. It only "requires" that the JavaFX modules be resolved from the module-path. Even then, it's actually possible to load JavaFX from the class-path, but that's an unsupported configuration. If your project depends on non-modular libraries, then I suggest making your project non-modular regardless of JavaFX. Automatic modules negate a major benefit provided by modules: The ability to create a jlink-ed runtime image that includes your own module (note jpackage can work with non-modular applications).

That said, that IllegalAccessError is a different (though possibly related) problem. We would need to see the full error and preferably a [mre] demonstrating it.
